# I do not understand this Splice behaviour in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have made a function that randomizes the order of answers in a quiz builder.
I pass in an array, the elements contain a question, some answers, and some other info. The correct answer is always in index 2 and this position needs to be randomized before a quiz question is generated.

```js
function randomiseAnswers(question)
{
//return an array with 5 elements, 0 to 4. Element 4 contains the index of the correct answer.
//INPUT PARAM = Topic;  Question;   Correct;    Distractor; Erroneous;  Erroneous;  Resource
var correct = question[2];
var answers = [];
var temp = question;
temp.splice(2,4);
shuffleArray(answers);
answers.push(answers.indexOf(correct))//make sure final element is the position of the correct answer

//Logger.log(answers);
return answers;
}
```

When I use this function, the original array that is passed to the function is being modified even though I only use a splice on a copy of the array called 'temp' inside the function.

When I replace the splice method with some push()es instead the original array remains intact and the function works as intended.
Why would splice modifying the array 'question' when it is only being used on a temporary array?

Comment: Where do you think you are copying the array?

Comment: var temp = question;

Comment: You arent copying, just reassigning

Comment: Oh... so temp and question are now just two names for the same thing..? Why have I never noticed this before, so presumably if I did this. var foo = 'wibble'; var bar = foo; bar = "ni" then foo would now also contain "ni"?

Comment: You got that wrong. Strings are copied by value while objects and arrays are copied by reference

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use let/const instead of var. Var is outdated
2. To solve your problem:
   `const temp = [...question]`